# Deploy CakePHP 3 on Heroku fails to compile due to "failed to open dir"

Tags: php, cakephp, heroku, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I'm using Heroku that I've connected to my github repo ([link](https://github.com/Sobient/dosspirit2)). I'm trying to deploy the project via the dashboard, but whatever I do I get "Failed to open dir: No such file or directory" as an end result, failing the deploy.

**Here's an excerpt from the build log:**

```
> Generating optimized autoload files

> Cake\Composer\Installer\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump

> App\Console\Installer::postInstall

   Script App\Console\Installer::postInstall handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
    [ErrorException]                                                                                                                    

     scandir(/tmp/build_96b54691e642650c17d8c1d0b7d2f0a9/Sobient-dosspirit2-5e84585/tmp): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
```

**The complete build log**

Here's the complete build log output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/021ecb02d731cdc9e394

**Screenshot**

Here's a screenshot from the Heroku dashboard showing some of the build log and error:
[image]

I've read on other similar questions on StackOverflow that one should move any requirements from `require-dev` onto `require`, which I've done. You can see the composer.json file this project uses here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63f5158156e10d51e6f6

Is there an issue with the composer.json file or a bug with build stacks on Heroku for PHP-apps using Composer?

Comment: "that one should move any requirements" That doesnt make sense, you only need to put stuff in require that are needed for production. "bake" for example you never ever need there.

Comment: This was answered by the CakeDevs to be a bug by Heroku. Haven't tested if they (or Heroku) have fixed it since.